# get salesforce Contact details using api with php

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I want to get details as below:

```
1) SalesForce API details to fetch user information from extension number
2) SalesForce API details to fetch Contact information from dialed number
3) SalesForce API details to log calls into SalesForce
```

So can anybody tell me what is the prerequirement for call api?Like any account creation,username and password required?

Comment: Won't this be in their online docs?

Comment: I have not found anywhere in online docs?Do you have any idea or link which can be help me?

Comment: It'd be better if you did some searching and tried something first - can you start here? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm. I'd guess you need a search call with maybe a User object - I've no idea, never used SalesForce.

Comment: I have already referred that and also created account and tried to login using that customer key and secret key but not successed.There is no any example api found for get details.

Answer (score 1):

for (1) & (2) they're simple query calls, using the [soap](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) or [rest](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) api's you'd run a query,

1. `select id, name, {whatever} from user where phone = 'the phone #'`
2. `select id, name, {whatever} from contact where phone = 'the phone #'`

for (3) you would create a new record, typically a Task, with the relevant fields populated include the whoId field which would be the contactId of the person called.

You may find using one of the general purpose schema/query tools like [SoqlX](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/) or [Workbench](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench) useful as a discovery aid.